# How to improve a Doctriny query to retrieve huge quantity of data?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony2 project using Doctrine.
I created a function to retrieve stocks items.
It works well if my database contains less than 50 000 rows.
However, my project needs to deal with more than 2 000 000 rows and If I use the following request, It needs more than 1 minutes to display my page.

**Repository (StockRepository.php) :**

```
 public function findAllQuery() {

      $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->select(array('s','st','p'))           
                    ->join('s.store','st')
                    ->join('s.product','p')
                    ->orderBy('st.name','ASC');     
    return $query;     

    }
```

**Controller (StockController.php) :**

```
public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('LiveDataShopBundle:Stock')->findAllQuery();

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
                $entities, $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), 50
        );

        return array(
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        );
    }
```

**Entity (Stock.php) :**

```
<?php

namespace LiveData\Bundle\ShopBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**  * Stock  *  * @ORM\Table()  *
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="LiveData\Bundle\ShopBundle\Entity\StockRepository")
*/ class Stock {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \stdClass
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Store", inversedBy="stocks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id",  onDelete="set null")
     */
    private $store;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var \stdClass
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="stocks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id",  onDelete="set null")
     */
    private $product;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set store
     *
     * @param \stdClass $store
     * @return Stock
     */
    public function setStore($store)
    {
        $this->store = $store;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get store
     *
     * @return \stdClass 
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->store;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     * @return Stock
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \stdClass $product
     * @return Stock
     */
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \stdClass 
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    } }
```

Any idea to reduce the process time ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try catching queries in logs (app/logs/dev.log) and execute them separately to find out which operation is the slowest. Which version of doctrine did you use ? knp_paginator have various behavior depending on it : https://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components/blob/master/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Event/Subscriber/Paginate/Doctrine/ORM/QuerySubscriber.php#L30

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about doctrine 2 only doctrine 1. Like i see in your code you only displaying 50 at one time. If this is the case than try to do a count(*) on stocks put this into the paginator and load only 50 (offset and limit) per page. That should help a lot.

Or use sphinx/solr. But i think the problem is the big amout of data that has to be moved from db to doctrine2/symphony2 (2.000.000 rows), try to debug and get futher informations.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is in mapping from db to objects, try to enable apc (for example) cache:

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

Comment: Using APC doesn't improve the execution in my case.